# Dataframe forward-fill till column-specific last valid index

Tags: pandas, dataframe, missing-data, ffill

How do I go from:

```
[In]:   df = pd.DataFrame({
            'col1': [100, np.nan, np.nan, 100, np.nan, np.nan],
            'col2': [np.nan, 100, np.nan, np.nan, 100, np.nan]
        })
        df

[Out]:        col1    col2
        0      100     NaN
        1      NaN     100
        2      NaN     NaN
        3      100     NaN
        4      NaN     100
        5      NaN     NaN
```

To:

```
[Out]:        col1    col2
        0      100     NaN
        1      100     100
        2      100     100
        3      100     100
        4      NaN     100
        5      NaN     NaN
```

My current approach is a to apply a custom method that works on one column at a time:

```
[In]:   def ffill_last_valid(s):
            last_valid = s.last_valid_index()
            s = s.ffill()
            s[s.index > last_valid] = np.nan
            return s

        df.apply(ffill_last_valid)
```

But it seems like an overkill to me. Is there a one-liner that works on the dataframe directly?

---

**Note on accepted answer:**

See the accepted answer from `mozway` below.

I know it's a tiny dataframe but:

[image]

Comment: Note that the `method='linear'` of interpolate only behaves like `ffill` if you have the same value before and after the NaNs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html), then keep only the values before the last stretch of NaN with a combination of [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) and [`notna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.notna.html)/reversed-[`cummax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cummax.html):

```
out = df.ffill().where(df[::-1].notna().cummax())
```

variant:

```
out = df.ffill().mask(df[::-1].isna().cummin())
```

Output:

```
    col1   col2
0  100.0    NaN
1  100.0  100.0
2  100.0  100.0
3  100.0  100.0
4    NaN  100.0
5    NaN    NaN
```

##### [`interpolate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html):

In theory, `df.interpolate(method='ffill', limit_area='inside')` should work, but while both options work as expected separately, for some reason it doesn't when combined (pandas 1.5.2). This works with `df.interpolate(method='zero', limit_area='inside')`, though.

Comment: Amazing discovery. It'll work if you give it a `limit=3` for instance. this is actually perfect for my usecase.